# What would happen if root CA get hacked?

Tags: tls, certificate-authority

What would happen if PKI for root CA is insecure? Let's say that one of the root Certificate Authorities was hacked and nobody noticed it yet.

Are all websites insecure or only those that were signed by this authority? Does it mean that a hacker is able to sign a new cert for any website and commit an MITM attack anywhere?